# How can I pass the following argument and what kind is it?

Tags: c, derivative

I am relatively new in C and found the code of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317868/recursively-find-the-second-derivative). How do you pass the argument `double (*f)(double)` of the function and how does the pointer works out in this?

Here's the function:

```
double derivative(double (*f)(double), double x0, int order)
```

My guess was that first you need something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

double f(double x){
    return pow(x,2);
} 

int main(){
    double x = 2;
    int order = 2;
    derivative(f(x), x , 2);
}
```

I tried it but it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ^ is exclusive or, not exponentiation. What you mean is `x*x` instead of `x^2`

Comment: `I tried it but it didn't work` What didn't work? Compile error? What was it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double (*f)(double)` is a function pointer. It means you need to pass a pointer to (or just the name of) a function. In your attempt, you're calling the function, then passing the return value, which isn't correct.

The correct way would be:

```
derivative(f, x, 2);
```